# I can no lognger use orignal docker after installing rootless-kit, only rootless mode can work

Tags: docker, moby, rootless

After installing rootless-kit, the original docker cannot be used.
When I execute the command "**sudo docker images**", it only shows the images downloaded in rootless mode.
Even if the environment variables in the ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile files are commented out, the result is still the same.
If I want to use the original docker, what environment variables should I delete?
What caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

unset DOCKER_HOST environmental variable